# PHP and AJAX Error In Receiving Data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, class

I have an input field on my website. When users start to type the name of their school in this input field, the `<select>` tag below should automatically do the following:
 1. Access my JavaScript file (*this works*)
 2. The JavaScript file should retrieve the value of the `<input>` and pass it onto a PHP file (*this works*)
 3. The PHP file should receive the string that has been sent (*this works*)
 4. The PHP file should create 3 variables within the class `FetchSchool`:
 5. The first variable is `_string` which will hold the value of the passed string from the `<input>` (*this variable may be part of the problem*)
6. The 2nd variable is the `_output` which will hold the value of what is to output to the JavaScript file (*I am not having any problems with this variable*)
7. The 3rd variable is the `_DM` variable, which connects to my `DataManager` class (*this is the one that is **extremely** problematic*)
What happens in my code is that nothing placed after the declaration of the `_DM` variable in the `__construct` function actually occurs. If I comment the declaration of the `_DM` variable out with `//`, then everything after that point works. I have checked and the `DataManager` class *can* be found by the `FetchSchool` class, so I cannot figure out why this error is occuring.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
class FetchSchool {
    public $_string;    // string that will hold the value that is passed in
    public $_output;    // output string of HTML
    public $_DM;
    final public function __construct($_passed_string){
        echo "<option>".$_passed_string."</option>";
        $this->_string = ($_passed_string) ? $_passed_string : "";
        $this->_output = "";
        $this->_DM     = ($_passed_string) ? new DataManager("localhost","root","root","hw_share") : NULL;
        if ($this->_string){
            echo "<option>works</option>";
        } // end if
        else {return "";}
    } // end __construct
} // end class fetchSchool
if (@$_GET["str"]){
    $_fetch_school = new FetchSchool(@$_GET["str"]);
} // end if
?>
```

The `"<option>".$_passed_string."</option>"` works and automatically displays whatever the user types, but the `"<option>works</option>"` does not show up, although it should.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `"<option>works</option>"` is not being `echo`-ed is either because `$this->_string` is empty or there is something wrong with the line

```
$this->_DM  = ($_passed_string) ? new DataManager("localhost","root","root","hw_share") : NULL;
```

and that stopped the php script from running.

Since in this case `$this->_string` does not appear to be empty, I'm pretty sure that something has gone wrong when you were creating a DataManager instance at that line.

You'll have to post the codes of how you create the class `DataManager` or else there is nothing much we can do about it.